# What Checklist should be followed before removing the user from org github if the user has left the organisation?

Tags: github

Is there any metadata level effect on github repos while deleting the user from github.

What things should be kept in mind before deleting the user from github once he leaves the organisation ?

Comment: _"What things should be kept in mind before deleting the user from github once he leaves the organisation?"_ - anxiety about unscrupulous ex-employees reappropriating company IP...

Comment: I don't you can delete a user from GitHub.  You can remove their access to your repos, and membership of your GitHub Organization, but their actual user account is theirs.